# Active Directory Authentication for sqsh

Tags: active-directory, sqsh

I am new user for sqsh to work with SQL Server from linux box.
Iuse sqsh passing servername username and password with -S,-U paramters.
I am logged to linux box with active directory credentials.
Can someone suggest how I can log to sql server from sqsh with active directory credentials
so that I amy not to type password each time

Answer (score 0):

Sqsh supports single sign on using Kerberos authentication to SAP ASE servers. Take a look at the -K, -R, -V and -Z parameters in the documentation and maybe you can get it to work with MSSQL as well. Unfortunately I do not have the right environment setup with AD to test this out myself.

Comment: Just thinking that this is currently not supported by freetds.

Comment: FreeTDS does claim to support AD ("Domain Logins") according to their [User Guide](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/domains.htm). I don't know whether they claimed to do so when you posted your comment.